Dataset scaling in a Chart.js bar chart for better comparison
I’m using Chart.js to graph two datasets on the same bar chart for a time-based comparison (x-axis). However, I’m encountering an issue where the height of one graph squashes or expands to fit the height of the other, making it difficult to compare them effectively.
For example, the purple graph below increases by 26x, while the blue graph increases by only 5x. Due to the scaling, it’s hard to assess the impact of these changes, as the purple graph is squashed into the height of the blue graph.
I think starting the purple graph at the same level as the blue graph at the first data point might help, but I’m concerned that the data will still be squashed to fit the blue graph’s height.
Are there specific Chart.js settings or configurations I can adjust to improve the comparability of these datasets?
My code for chart scales is as follows:
y: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    grid:  {
        display: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        drawOnChartArea: false,
     },
     ticks: {
        display: true,
     },
   },
},
y1: {
     beginAtZero: true,
     position: 'right',
     grid: {
        display: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        drawOnChartArea: false,
     },
     ticks: {
        display: true,
     },
   },
}

Current graph

Expected graph


Since you already set different, independent y axes for the two datasets, you decoupled the vertical scaling of those datasets. If bounds: 'data' were set, the maximum values for both datasets would be represented to the full height of the chart area, regardless of how they relate to one another. With the current bounds: 'ticks', there will be a small gap to the next integer multiple of the tick step, but that difference is specific to each dataset. Given that, it is unclear what else you want to achieve.

Put another way, I would like to see how 2 data sets have changed since the start of the period. It is easier to perform this assessment if they start at the same level on the Y axis (i.e. 1st data points are aligned) and diverge from that point as opposed to how the graph is currently set up where the highest datapoints are aligned.
I'll edit the initial post to include an illustration of the desired outcome.

There isn't a chart.js option that would arrange the values such that the first bars of the two datasets have equal height,
but it can be arranged by computing the value of axes max dynamically, like in this fiddle.
Please let me know how that fits into your framework.

Thanks @kikon, computing the max value dynamically works using your suggested computeMax function

There isn't a chart.js option that would arrange the values such that the first bars of the
two datasets have equal height, but it can be arranged by computing the value of axes
max dynamically:
function computeMax(which, data){
    // computes max for scale `which` (0 -> 'y', 1 -> 'y1') such that the first
    // bars of the two datasets have the same height
    const other = 1 - which,
        dataValues = data.datasets.map(dataset=>dataset.data),
        dataMax = dataValues.map(data => Math.max(...data)),
        firstToMax = dataValues.map((data, i) => data[0] / dataMax[i])
    if(firstToMax[which] > firstToMax[other]){
        return firstToMax[which]/firstToMax[other] * dataMax[which];
    }
    else{
        return dataMax[which];
    }
}

the function computeMax being called for the scriptable
max property of each axis, like this:
options: {
    ........... other options
    scales: {
        y: {
            .......... other y axis options
             ticks: {
                 display: true,
                 includeBounds: false
             },
             max: ({chart}) => computeMax(0, chart.data)
        },
        y1: {
            .......... other y1 axis options
            ticks: {
                 display: true,
                 includeBounds: false
             },
             max: ({chart}) => computeMax(1, chart.data)
        }
    }
}      

Here's a snippet that includes that piece of code:


function computeMax(which, data){
    // computes max for scale `which` (0 -> 'y', 1 -> 'y1') such that the first
    // bars of the two datasets have the same height
    const other = 1 - which,
        dataValues = data.datasets.map(dataset=>dataset.data),
        dataMax = dataValues.map(data => Math.max(...data)),
        firstToMax = dataValues.map((data, i) => data[0] / dataMax[i])
    if(firstToMax[which] > firstToMax[other]){
        return firstToMax[which]/firstToMax[other] * dataMax[which];
    }
    else{
        return dataMax[which];
    }
}


const config = {
    type: "bar",

    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 2023,
                data: [20, 65, 80, 102, 55, 56, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55],
            },
            {
                label: 2024,
                data: [50, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 108, 80, 81, 56, 55].map(x => x * 10),
                yAxisID: 'y1'
            },
        ]
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            y: {
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    drawOnChartArea: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    includeBounds: false
                },
                max: ({chart}) => computeMax(0, chart.data)
            },
            y1: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                position: 'right',
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    includeBounds: false
                },
                max: ({chart}) => computeMax(1, chart.data)
            },
        }
    }
};

new Chart('myChart', config);
<div style="height: 300px">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



Since the axes had beginAtZero set true it was clear that all the values are
positive. A generalization with multiple datasets and including negative values
can be found in this fiddle.
